# Autocomplete existing variable names in Sublime Text 2

Tags: macos, autocomplete, sublime-text-2

On my Windows machine I also use ST2, but it handles autocomplete of existing variable names in the current file. How do I enable this in ST2 on my mac? Syntax is PHP

Comment: It usually does when you press Tab. Have you installed any packages like SublimeCodeIntel on your Windows PC?

Comment: Good question... It's been there for as long as I can remember. Any way to lookup installed packages?

Comment: `Cmd-Shift-P` (or `Ctrl-Shift-P` on Windows), then type `List Packages` — at least if you have Package Control installed.

Comment: Ok, I found it... CodeIgniter autocompletion got in the way... If you can provide an answer I'll be happy to approve as a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Package Control installed, there's probably a particular package that's causing the issue.

Check your installed packages by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> (or <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> on a Mac) and typing `list packages`.

You could then, for example, remove offending packages (by typing `remove packages`).